# Git: Howto move changes since last commit to a new branch

Tags: git, branch, checkout, git-commit, git-checkout

I have been working on a branch which we can call "A". I just realized that the code I have added since I last committed should rather be in a specific (experimental) branch, but not in "A". How can I commit the changes to a new branch and leave branch "A" as it was when I last committed?

Comment: Simple question, simple answer :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the changes are staged or your working directory, you can simply checkout into a new branch like so:

```
git checkout -b branch_name
```

You can then commit directly into the new branch.

Comment: Sometimes things are just too simple. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Siggi: You might want to accept this answer so others with the same question can find it more easily (and to give credit to Blair).

Comment: Done, I just couldn't do it when he posted the answer because of the "accept answer" time limit... and then I forgot.

Answer (score 5):

```
git stash
git checkout branch-A
git stash pop
```